# Pyomo: is possible to assign to a design variable only defined values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, pyomo, coin-or

I want that a design variable assumes only specified values during optimization process.

For example:
Let x be the variable which can assume only specific value, e.g.:

```py
x = [0.1,0.5,1.0,1.7,2.3]
```

How can be written in python using pyomo (if it's possible)?

I hope I was clear.

Comment: You might want to edit your question to make it clear that you are looking for a syntax that will allow you to define variables like this automatically -- not for a modeling trick in which you declare new variables to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3):

You have to do this with integer variables. For example, if there are `N` possible values of `x`, then let `x[n] = 1` if `x` equals the `n`th possible value, and `0` otherwise. Any time you have an `x` in your original model, replace it with

```
sum {n=1,...,N} v[n] * x[n]
```

where `v[n]` is the `n`th possible value. Finally, add a constraint that says:

```
sum {n=1,...,N} x[n] == 1
```

I'm not writing these in Pyomo syntax, but this is a general modeling approach that is the same no matter what modeling language/package you use.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've already modelled the problem as a MINLP, i've already defined the variable as an integer variable. But now i want to be more specific.

Comment: More specific about what? Are you asking whether you can model variables that come from a discrete set, in Pyomo, *without* declaring new integer variables?

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself clearly, I'm sorry. What I want to do is declare that my variable can take only specific values, such as those in a list, which I fill personally.

Comment: In that case, I don't think it's possible to do this automatically. For example, if you declare `model.A = Set(initialize=[0.1,0.5,1.0,1.7,2.3])` and then declare your variable like `model.x = Var(domain=model.A)`, Pyomo gives an error that the domain is not continuous, integer or binary -- suggesting that those are the only allowable domains. However, note that even if Pyomo *could* do what you are asking, it would still convert to integer variables "behind the scenes", so it might be easier syntactically but it would not be faster computationally.